# For Loop Shows All Steps One By One & Not The Final One Directly

Tags: python, macos

I have been learning Python from this YouTube video [Python Tutorial For Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc&t=8040s) by Programming With Mosh.

At (2:26:28) in the video, instructor has given an exercise to write a program to convert the numbers from a phone number into words. I tried doing that. I am currently using Pycharm with Python 3.8.2 on a Mac.

This is what I wrote:

```
number = input('Phone: ')
number_in_words = {
    '1': 'One',
    '2': 'Two',
    '3': 'Three',
    '4': 'Four'
}
final_output = ''
for words in number:
    final_output += number_in_words.get(words) + ' '
    print(final_output)
```

And this is the output:

```
Phone: 1234
One 
One Two 
One Two Three 
One Two Three Four
```

I, however, only want the last line on the terminal, and not the rest.

Comment: Take the `print()` call out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Don't indent the last line

```
for words in number:
    final_output += number_in_words.get(words) + ' '

print(final_output)
```

Now it's outside the loop and will be printed once.

Comment: Glad to help :-))

Answer (score 1):

Simply You have to call print() statement outside the body of the loop like this:

```
number = input('Phone: ')
number_in_words = {
    '1': 'One',
    '2': 'Two',
    '3': 'Three',
    '4': 'Four'
}
final_output = ''
for words in number:
    final_output += number_in_words.get(words) + ' '
print(final_output)
```

Ouput:

```
Phone: 123                                                                                                            
One Two Three
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
for words in number:
    final_output += number_in_words.get(words) + ' '
print(final_output)
```

Comment: If it helped you, please accept the answer in order to help other people struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

your print() should not in loop,

```
    final_output += number_in_words.get(words) + ' '

print(final_output)`
```

Comment: Tried this answer:
  File "file1.py", line 12
    print(final_output)`
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax